# Prove that $d_n$ is constant in the case of compound interest

Tags: finance

the question is asking me to Prove that $d_n$ is constant in the case of compound interest.

What I know so far and have tried is the formula for compound interest is $a(t)=(1+i)^t$ and I think that $d_n$ is possibly supposed to represent the discount maybe. But I there is no $d_n$ in the formula for compound interest so I am confused on how I am supposed to prove this.

Comment: $d_n$ is the initial capital?

Comment: Have a look in your papers and see what $d_n$ means. This is the simplest way.

Comment: $$Amount= P(1+ \frac{R}{100})^t $$ . 
There is no discount term anywhere. Check your question again

Comment: the question in my text only says "prove that $d_n$ is constant in the case of compound interest" there is no other information in the question. That is all I have been able to figure out

Comment: some of the other formulas I have found with $d_n$ are: $d_n$= a(n)-a(n-1) / a(n)$ which is the formula for the effective rate of discount in the nth year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ a(n) = P (1+i)^n $$

$$ d_n = \frac{P (1+i)^n -P (1+i)^{n-1} }{P (1+i)^n }  = 1-(1+i)^{-1}  $$
which does not depend on $n$

Comment: so if it doesn't depend on n, that means that $d_n$ will stay constant correct?

Comment: that is correct !